# Initializing the stack in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, gnu-assembler

I have *very* little experience writing code in assembly.

I have the following code:

```
.globl main
.type main, @function
main:
  movq $0, %rax
  pushq %rax
```

And get a seg fault when the resulting program is run. In GDB, it looks like somewhere something is trying to access `0x0`, which of course is no bueno.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I'm thinking this is because `%rsp` isn't pointed at a valid address when I try to `pushq`, but--I haven't had any luck finding out how to initialize the stack in x86 or even if I need to--and if not, what's going wrong here.

Comment: probably because your code lacks a `ret` instruction to return to the _C_ runtime that called main (which in turn would close your program)

Comment: @Michael Petch - If I remove the `pushq` line, everything is fine. If I add a `ret` after `pushq`, no change.

Comment: Yes, if you push something on the stack you have to pop it off before the `ret`. The problem isn't the stack being invalid, it is that you are not rebalancing it and then doing `ret`.So before `ret` you'd have to do `add $8, %rsp` or pop the value.Failure to rebalance the stack as it was at the time `main` is called will cause the wrong value to be popped when the `ret` tries to return to the caller (bad address on stack will likely cause `ret` to fault.

Comment: Whoa. Nice. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Guhhh. I've read over a hundred pages in this class and--that hadn't come up, yet. It worked. Of course. Thank you, again.

Comment: Try to use Intel instruction documentation to cross-check your class literature, for example reading few times [`call`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) and [`ret`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html) should give you the idea the content of stack actually matters a lot to the `ret`, and the CPU is not aware of any "being inside function" or "recursion depth" and similar high level concepts, it treats every instruction separately and individually, if it hits `ret`, it will just take the value from stack and jump there, nothing more "subroutine"-related is in the CPU.

Comment: In asm, every instruction has well-defined rules for how it changes the architectural state of the machine.  `ret` is `pop %rip`, nothing more nothing less.  (You can't actually write `pop %rip`, but it does pop the stack and put the result into the program counter.)  As Ped7g said, it's up to you to make sure `%rsp` is pointing to an address you want to jump to when `ret` runs.